# How to get Non inventory item to be printed in picking Ticket form in NetSuite?

Tags: netsuite

I am using the Advanced PDF/HTML Template
Custom Picking Ticket PDF/HTML Template
I have some inventory items as well as non-inventory items 
at the sales order 
but the point is 
when I hit the print button I get only the inventory items 
is there any way around to add the non-inventory items

I am trying to find where Netsuite filter the Sales order item list to print inventory items only

Answer (score 1):

There is a preference that you can toggle to control this. Under `Setup > Accounting > Accounting Preferences > Order Management`, make sure that `Show Non-Inventory Items on Printed Forms` is checked.